# Bootstrap Accordion won't open

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap Accordion in my Angular project. For some unknown reasons the views are rendering but the collapse doesn't seems to work. Clicking on it does not open/extend the contents inside. As a sample I copied the exact example from official Bootstrap 5.0 documentation which still doesn't work for me as the same problem persists.

below is the code.

```css
input[type="text"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Details
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Address" class="control-label">Address<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              More Details
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <p>some stuff</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Even More Details
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <p>some more stuff</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Json file for the project

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"my-app": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "sass"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:application": {
      "strict": true
    }
  },
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
       
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
       
        "scripts": []
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "tsconfig.app.json",
          "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"defaultProject": "my-app"}
```

Help me find out what is going wrong. Thank you for reading!

Comment: are you using ng-bootstrap?

Comment: @user3929590 no

Comment: in the html, I can only see the css files under head. I think bootstrap also has a js file to be included as the accordian will require some js. Can you try importing the js file and check?

Comment: try adding this <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @user3929590 i tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: try adding the JS and check if it works, if not then I would recommend to use ng-bootstrap as it will allow you to inject the specific accordian module in your app and then you can use it.